# Probability of Next Bernoulli Trial conditioned on Sum of Bernoullis

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the correct way to approach this probability?

$$
P(X_{n+1} = 1 | S_{n} = r)
$$

where

$$
X_{1},...,X_{n+1}
$$
are conditionally independent bernoulli trials with success probability U where U has a uniform(0,1) distribution, i.e.:
$$
P(X_{i} = 1 | U) = U
$$
 and
$$
S_{n} = X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n}
$$

My attempt:
$$
\frac{P(X_{n+1} = 1,S_{n} = r)}{P(S_{n} = r)}
$$

$$
\frac{P(S_{n+1} = r + 1)}{P(S_{n} = r)}
$$

then solved similarly to:
[Conditional Probability Involving Sum of Bernoulli Trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410460/conditional-probability-involving-sum-of-bernoulli-trials)

Comment: Conditionally independent of what?

Comment: In ordinary usage Bernoulli trials are independent, fixed probability events.  It appears you are asking about the probability of success in the $n+1$'st trial, given the sum of successes in the previous $n$ trials.  But if the $n+1$'st trial is independent of the previous trials, conditioning on that sum should not change the probability of success.

Comment: @hardmath They are not independent, since the Bernoulli parameter is itself a uniform random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $s \in \{0, \ldots, m\}$, the law of total probability yields
$$P(S_m = s) = \int_0^1 P(S_m = s \mid U = u) \, du = \binom{m}{s} \int_0^1 u^s (1-u)^{m-s} \, du = \binom{m}{s} \frac{s!(m-s)!}{(m+1)!} = \frac{1}{m+1}.$$
[I cheated when computing the integral by using the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) PDF.]
So actually, the marginal distribution of $S_m$ is uniform over $\{0, \ldots, m\}$.

---

You made an error at the end of your post: $P(X_{n+1} = 1, S_n = r)$ does **not** equal $P(S_{n+1} = r+1)$. ($S_{n+1} = r+1$ does not necessarily imply $S_n = r$.) My original answer overlooked this mistake.

The denominator is $P(S_n = r) = \frac{1}{n+1}$.
The numerator is
$$\begin{align}P(X_{n+1} = 1, S_n = r)
&= \int_0^1 P(X_{n+1} = 1 \mid U=u) P(S_n = r \mid U = u) \, du
\\
&= \int_0^1 u \cdot \binom{n}{r} u^r (1-u)^{n-r} \, du
\\
&= \binom{n}{r} \frac{(r+1)!(n-r)!}{(n+2)!}\\ &= \frac{r+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align}$$

Combining everything yields $$\frac{(r+1)/((n+1)(n+2))}{1/(n+1)} = \frac{r+1}{n+2}.$$
This sense because if $r$ is closer to $n$, you would suspect that $U$ is large too, which would make $X_{n+1} = 1$ more likely.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful

Comment: @user1992460 My original answer had a mistake.