# Conditional probability involving sum of non-identical Bernoulli Trials

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I have $X_i \space (i=1,\cdots ,n)$ which has Bernoulli($p_i$), **where $p_i$s are different**.

(independent non-identical Bernoulli trials).

I am having trouble finding the conditional probability of $X_i$ given $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n = K$

($K < n$).

Is there any exact solution or approximation for $ P(X_i=1 | X_1 + \cdots + X_n = K )$ ?

---

I found that there is the exact solution when $p_i$s are the same (for independent identical Bernoulli trials).

([Conditional Probability Involving Sum of Bernoulli Trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410460/conditional-probability-involving-sum-of-bernoulli-trials?newreg=a3a04b425ce346eb91325251b7cc9ea2))

Answer (score 0):

Applying Bayes rule and writing $q_i=1-p_i$ it can be deduced that:$$P\left(X_{i}=1\mid S_{n}=k\right)=\frac{p_{i}P\left(S_{n}-X_{i}=k-1\right)}{p_{i}P\left(S_{n}-X_{i}=k-1\right)+q_{i}P\left(S_{n}-X_{i}=k\right)}$$

Comment: Thx for the answer. So is there any exact solution for that? Something only represented with p_i's?